# Need help on regular expression in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, regex

I am trying to trim a particular word using SQL Server. Eg: I have a table with below data:

```
Column1  | Column2
---------+-----------------
Test1    | ABC->IT->CDE
Test2    | ABCD->OT->FGH
```

I trying to get the output as:

```
Column1 | Column2
--------+----------
Test1   |  CDE
Test2   |  FGH
```

i.e. trying to trim till the 2nd arrow "->" and display only the word after that. I have tried using stuff and charindex.

```
case 
   when Column2 like '%->%' 
      then stuff(Column2, 1, charindex('%[A-Z]%->%[A-Z]%->',Column2),'')   
      else null 
end as Test
```

Not sure if this works. Can you help me out to get this output.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best solution would be to stop storing delimited values. Then it becomes trivial to retrieve the data you want. Delimited values violates 1NF.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you your split.

```
SELECT 
   Column1,
   REVERSE(LEFT(reverse(Column2), charindex('>', reverse(Column2)) - 1)) as Column2
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
DECLARE @t as Varchar(255) = 'ABC->IT->CDE'

select REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@t), 0, CHARINDEX(REVERSE('->'), REVERSE(@t))))
```

where @t is your column

Comment: You're welcome. If possible check the answer as "resolve" to help other user. Otherwise, as @sean suggest, you may try to storing data in better way!

Answer (score 0):

While not strictly necessary I would recommend keeping your logic for parsing the string in a user defined function.  If you need to improve or update your string parsing logic you can simply update the function without changing the rest of your queries.

Based on your description you either want the 3rd word of the string or the last word in the string. I am assuming that you want the 3rd word and that the number of words in the string can be variable. The following function should return what you want.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetThirdWord 
(
    @inputString    VARCHAR(200),
    @delimitor      VARCHAR(10)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @delimitorLength INT = LEN(@delimitor);

    DECLARE @firstDelimitor INT = charindex('->', @inputString);
    DECLARE @secondDelimitor INT = charindex('->', @inputString, @firstDelimitor + @delimitorLength);
    DECLARE @thirdDelimitor INT = charindex('->', @inputString, @secondDelimitor + @delimitorLength);

    IF @secondDelimitor > 0 
    BEGIN

        IF @thirdDelimitor = 0 
            SET @thirdDelimitor = LEN(@inputString);

        SET @result = SUBSTRING(@inputString, @secondDelimitor + @delimitorLength, @thirdDelimitor - @secondDelimitor - @delimitorLength)

    END

    RETURN @result;

END
```

The function can be called as follow:

```
SELECT  Column1,
        dbo.GetThirdWord(Column2, '->') AS Column2
FROM    YourTableName
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given me enough information to be sure that this would work, but if the format is always the same for the rows you're trying to do this on, you could very easily perform the following:

```
select right(Column2,3)
into #NewColumn
from YourTable
where YourConditionsHere
```

No regex necessary